# UK Immigration Exit Rules

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

I'm currently working in UK with Tier-2 ICT visa, Can I stay for 3 or 4 days after my visa got expired in order to close my UK bank account, clear dues and finishing personal things if any?

Answer (score 3):

No, per the UKVI answer to this freedom of information request. You must leave the U.K. within the expiry date of your existing visa unless you have an outstanding application with UKVI.

Source: https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/is_there_a_grace_period_after_ex